# Multiple columns of data import per node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to have multiple columns of information on a Name node when importing a csv? For example, Name is John Doe, Company, Position is President of Sales, Located in California, etc., on a single node. If so, any suggestions on how to merge that information in a single name node in cypher during upload?  Lets say I have columns of information as Position, State, County, Phone.  So far All I've been able to come up with is the Name and relation to the Company that he/she works for.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///company_name.csv' AS line
MERGE (C:Company {Company: line.Company })
MERGE (N:Name {Name: line.Name })
MERGE (C)<-[:works_for]-(N);
```

Comment: Forgive me, but it is unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish. If you want multiple properties in the same node (which maybe should be Person then instead of Name) you just specify them separated by commas : MERGE (p:Person {Name: line.Name, Phone: line.Phone}). What is useful is to create a unique constraint on the property that is ... unique for your node before doing the LOAD, for example CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.personID IS UNIQUE;

Comment: My apologies, I meant to say multiple properties.  I'll give the CREATE CONSTRAINT ON approach a try.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to use `ON CREATE SET` and `ON MATCH SET` after creating/matching the node with `MERGE` on a unique key value.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///company_name.csv' AS line
MERGE (C:Company {Company: line.Company })
MERGE (N:Name {Name: line.Name })
ON CREATE SET 
    N.Position = line.Position,
    N.Location = line.Location,
    N.Country = line.Country,
    N.Phone = line.Phone 
ON MATCH SET 
    N.Position = line.Position,
    N.Location = line.Location,
    N.Country = line.Country,
    N.Phone = line.Phone   
MERGE (C)<-[:works_for]-(N);
```

Alternatively you can set everything on a single node but if there are multiple rows in your csv file that correspond to the same identity and some of the values you are setting are different on those rows then it will result in multiple nodes in the database afterwards.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///company_name.csv' AS line
MERGE (C:Company {Company: line.Company })
MERGE (N:Name {Name: line.Name, Position: line.Position, Location line.Location, Country: line.Country, Phone: line.Phone })
MERGE (C)<-[:works_for]-(N);
```

Comment: I've just tried
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///company1.csv' AS line
    MERGE (C:Company {Company: line.Company })
    ON CREATE SET
    C.Partner = line.Partner
    C.Product = line.Product
    C.Partner_Value = line.Partner_Value
    C.Partners = line.Partners
    C.Customers = line.Customers
    ON MATCH SET
    C.Partner = line.Partner
    C.Product = line.Product
    C.Partner_Value = line.Partner_Value
    C.Partners = line.Partners

Error
Invalid input '.': expected 'o/O', 'r/R' or 'a/A' (line 5, column 2 (offset: 188))
"C.Product = line.Product"
  ^

Comment: it looks like you are missing the commas in between the different properties